# Why do you think the Java language chooses to treat file data as a stream rather than as a single object?

Tags: java, file

Why do you think the Java language chooses to treat file data as a stream rather than as a single object? What are the benefits of this approach?

Comment: Can you explain what it would mean to tread file data as a single object?

Comment: Define "as a single object". The benefit is that files are handled the same way as every other stream--not all data is always available at once.

Answer (score 8):

Consider loading a 4 GB file into your application as an object....

If thats not good enough consider handling 50 of those files simultanously and think about how much memory that would require.

Btw there is a high level [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class for doing high level operations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you define "a stream" and a "single object".

Assuming that random access is what distinguishes the two, the answer is that the abstraction of streams is more general and supports not only disk files, but also sockets, pipes and other communication channels.

Answer (score 1):

[The Unix file System](http://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/files/) is the source of this idea. Standard input, standard output and standard error are treated as streams:

A file is simply a data stream - one byte after another with no inherent internal structure imposed by Unix. Programs interpret how to divide this stream into lines or records or fields.

By convention, Unix programs that deal with text generally break up the stream of bytes into lines wherever a new line control character is found (octal code 012). This is only a convention. It is not imposed by the operating system and different programs could use different ways to indicate the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Java can "treat" the input stream as an object too if you tell it what the object is.

```
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath));
MyObject myobject = (MyObject) objectInput.readObject();
```

Here is a basic tutorial on input/output streams:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Answer (score 0):

Streams provide better abstaction. You can convert file data into an object using streams, if you need, or continue read the stream if not all data available yet.